# Calling php page with ajax is not working

Tags: php, ajax

I'm having problem with calling php page with ajax. When I click the button, the chart.php is not displayed. Both of the buttons don't work. The target php files are the same with different data only, so I included only one of the chart.php pages. How can I fix this? please. Thanks for your help!

Index.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Charts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="etc/main.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="etc/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">

            <button id='actbutton1'> Chart1</button>
            <button id='actbutton2'> Chart2</button>
        </div>

        <div id="contentliquid">
            <div id="content">

                <div id="querydiv">

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="leftcolumn">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('actbutton1').onclick = function() {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", "chart1.php", true);

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("querydiv").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                }
            }
            xhr.send();
        }

        document.getElementById('actbutton2').onclick = function() {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", "chart2.php", true);

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("querydiv").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                }
            }
            xhr.send();
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

The page I call with ajax, chart1.php, is this:

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = ""; 
    $dbname = "mydb";  

    $con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($con->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
    }
    else
    {

    }
    $query = "SELECT Week, Omean FROM charts"; 
    $aresult = $con->query($query);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chart1</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart(){

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();    
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

                ['Week','Omean'],
                <?php
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($aresult)){
                        echo "['".$row["Week"]."', ".$row["Omean"]."],";
                    }
                ?>

               ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        view.setColumns([0, 1, {
        calc: 'stringify',
        sourceColumn: 1,
        type: 'string',
        role: 'annotation'    
    }]);            

            var options = {
                 title: 'Chart1',
                'width':1700,
                'height':600,
                 hAxis : {textStyle : {fontSize: 8}},
                'tooltip' : { trigger: 'none'},  
                 enableInteractivity: false,   
                 legend: { position: 'bottom' }
                     };    

               var chart = new             
    google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curvechart')); 
               chart.draw(data, options);        
            chart.draw(view, options);  // <-- use data view    
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="curvechart" style="width: 900px; height: 400px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "_Both of the buttons don't work_" What does that mean? Nothing triggered on click? Wrong results? No results?

Comment: yes, when I click the button no results are displayed. chart.php pages work on their own.

Comment: You cant load chart from ajax by chart1.php if you want to load chart you need  a json return values and load it in chart.php not chart1.php

Comment: ok, thank you, NigHamza.